# How to generate a variable framerate video with sync'd audio from a bunch of images and an audio file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, libav, ogg-theora

I've got a series of images captured using a motion activated camera-right now, I'm doing a bit of processing on them and each image is stored as a PNM/PBM file but I can easily convert them back to PNGs.   I have a unix timestamp of when each were first created.  I've also got an audio file (where I know the starting time), recorded over the same period.

Is there any way I can construct a lossless video that should be playable from VLC from these images?  Ideally, I'd like the audio to sync.

Comment: you'll probably have to "duplicate" frames so that their timestamp lines up with a set framerate (fps).  Though it's an interesting request, maybe file a feature request for it on ffmpeg trac?